# How to change the background color of a page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmark

I want to get the color as the following [example](http://www.sholabandb.com/uploads/1/4/7/6/14761310/ccritinerarygot1day.pdf),  I was trying the package tikz and tikzmark. Thank you very much for your contributions

Comment: Just use `xcolor`: it has a `\pagecolor` macro (name might be slightly wrong - just check the docs).

Comment: Please don't post questions which depend on external links: they become useless when the content of the linked sites changes. I guess you're just asking about background colour and have ignored the link anyway (too much hassle). If that's mistaken, please make your question complete here.

Comment: The "example" does not contain any background colors, it is using background *images*.

Answer (score 3):

Here an option using the background package, that allows to put text, graphics in some or all pages in your document, in combination with the graphicx package, on the configuration we have option to control the opacity, placement, angle, shifting, etc.

The background I used in the MWE was obtained from the document that you linked, imported page 2 in inkscape with the option Poppler/Cairo, and then I used ungroup to separate the background and erase the other elements to save it in a PDF format, here the document stored in some cloud folder [GOT-BG.pdf 908kb](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jy9kpUdGdPzsjQIWnL833NFW12rnAMfz), to obtain the "same" result put the pdf document in the same folder of the main latex document and compile two times with pdflatex.

PSD: the ducks may vary

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[bottom=2cm,top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[
pages=some,
firstpage=false,
opacity=0.8,
placement=center,
angle=0,
hshift=0,
vshift=0
]{background}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ducks}
\title{Background package application}
\author{J. Leon V.}

\begin{document}
    \backgroundsetup{contents={\includegraphics[scale=.103]{GOT-BG.pdf}}}
    \maketitle  
    \part{Some text in a beautifull old page}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}\\
        \caption{Example image}
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[4-6]
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}
            SCORE             & P & W & D & L & F  & A & Pts \\
            \hline
            Foo & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 10 & 5 & 12  \\
            Bar            & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3 &  8 & 9 &  9  \\
            baz          & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  7 & 8 &  7  \\
            Kstor   & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 & 8 &  7  \\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Example table}
    \end{table}
    \part{trying with ducks}
    \lipsum[7-9]
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw(0,0) circle (1pt);% typo has been fixed!
            \begin{scope}[xshift=.7cm]
            \randuck;
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[xshift=2.7cm]
            \randuck;
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[xshift=4.7cm]
            \randuck;
            \end{scope}

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Testing Tikz + ducks}      
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[10]    
\end{document}
```